# Why is BIOS time interpreted as BOOT time?

Tags: boot, bios

I checked up online the real definition of BIOS time and I discovered that **BIOS Time** is the time it takes for the **hardware** attached to the system to be **initialized** and not the time it takes for the **Operating System** to be loaded from the **Secondary Storage** which is also known as the **Boot Time**. Why do people misinterpret the two such that when they want to check the **Boot Time** they head over to **Task Manager*-->Startup* to check it when that is not the information they need?

Comment: "Why do people misinterpret the two" ?? I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve here.  Also, there is no BIOS on a modern computer.

Comment: The bios boots first, then it hands it off to the OS to boot. Boot means Bootstrap, a process from starting from nothing.

Comment: There is no BIOS on a modern computer, what do you mean? Your HP or Apple machine does not have a firmware, you got to be kidding me